# How to make the_tags title translatable?

Tags: theme-development, translation

How can I make the text in the_tags function translatable? Currently I'm using following:

```
<?php the_tags('<div class="tags">Post Tags',' ','</div>'); ?>
```

But I'd like to make 'Post Tags' text translatable by adding the text domain, similar to this:

```
_e('Post Tags', 'textdomain');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Translate the title before you send it to `the_tags()`:

```
the_tags(
    '<div class="tags">' . __( 'Post Tags', 'textdomain' ),
    ' ',
    '</div>'
);
```